# Filtering ng-repeat does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters, angularjs-ng-options

I have the following list of people with two pets each:

```
[
    {
        "animalOne": "dog",
        "animalTwo": "cat",
        "age": 37,
        "name": "Charles Andrews"
    },
    {
        "animalOne": "dog",
        "animalTwo": "cat",
        "age": 12,
        "name": "Anna Langston"
    },
    {
        "animalOne": "dog",
        "animalTwo": "iguana",
        "age": 43,
        "name": "Chris Oleander"
    },
    {
        "animalOne": "iguana",
        "animalTwo": "cat",
        "age": 13,
        "name": "Martin Stevens"
    },
    {
        "animalOne": "dog",
        "animalTwo": "parrot",
        "age": 23,
        "name": "Alana Anderson"
    },
    {
        "animalOne": "iguana",
        "animalTwo": "parrot",
        "age": 43,
        "name": "Mia Charles"
    },
    {
        "animalOne": "cat",
        "animalTwo": "goldfish",
        "age": 12,
        "name": "Yun Wong"
    },
    {
        "animalOne": "goldfish",
        "animalTwo": "parrot",
        "age": 32,
        "name": "Hannah Alveda"
    },
    {
        "animalOne": "iguana",
        "animalTwo": "cat",
        "age": 9,
        "name": "Sheena Morroning"
    }
]
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
$scope.filterOne = 'All animals';
$scope.filterTwo = 'All animals';

$scope.petsFilterList = [
    {
        label: 'All animals',
        value: 'All animals'
    },
    {
        label: 'dog',
        value: 'dog'
    },
    {
        label: 'cat',
        value: 'cat'
    },
    {
        label: 'parrot',
        value: 'parrot'
    },
    {
        label: 'iguana',
        value: 'iguana'
    },
    {
        label: 'goldfish',
        value: 'goldfish'
    }
];

$scope.petsFilter = function(person) {
    //console.log(person);
    console.log($scope.filterOne);
    console.log($scope.filterTwo);

    if ($scope.filterOne === 'All animals' && $scope.filterTwo === 'All animals') {
        return true;
    }

    if ($scope.filterOne !== 'All animals' && $scope.filterTwo === 'All animals') {
        return person.animalOne == $scope.filterOne;
    }

    if ($scope.filterOne === 'All animals' && $scope.filterTwo !== 'All animals') {
        return person.animalTwo == $scope.filterTwo;
    }

    if ($scope.filterOne !== 'All animals' && $scope.filterTwo !== 'All animals') {
        return person.animalOne == $scope.filterOne && person.animalTwo == $scope.filterTwo;
    }
};
```

In the template I have:

```
<div>
    <select ng-options="pet.value as pet.label for pet in petsFilterList" ng-model="filterOne">
    </select>
    <select ng-options="pet.value as pet.label for pet in petsFilterList" ng-model="filterTwo">
    </select>
</div>

<!-- Just for testing -->
<div>
    {{filterOne}} - {{filterTwo}}
</div>

<div class="pet" ng-repeat="person in customers | filter:petsFilter | orderBy: ['age', 'name']" ng-click="gotoPerson(person)">
    <div>{{person.name}} - {{person.age}}</div>
    <div>{{person.animalOne}} and {{person.animalTwo}}</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is that if I choose an animal in the first dropdown, only people that has that animal as "animalOne" should be displayed in the repeat, and if I choose an animal in the second dropdown, only people with that animal should be displayed. If I choose animals in both dropdowns, only people that have both corresponding animals (has to be exact, can't be mirrored) should be displayed.

My problem is that the "just for testing"-div shows the correct filters choosen from the dropdown, but the list does not get filtered, it always show all animals. When I change a value in the dropdown, the console.logs also always print "All animals". Can anyone see my mistake?

Comment: please provide runnable code/ jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I realised I could skip the filter and just use an `ng-if` inside the repeat:

```
<div class="pet" ng-repeat="person in customers | orderBy: ['age', 'name']" ng-click="gotoPerson(person)" ng-if="(filterOne == 'All animals' || filterOne == person.animalOne) && (filterTwo == 'All animals' || filterTwo == person.animalTwo)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter works correctly, I tried this code in [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/s8naq95x/).

The only problem I could assume that your Customer data might be refreshing back to normal state, check if it is same as assigned `$scope.customers`.